# Filtering ListView by SearchView's query - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, android, listview, searchview

As the topic's name mentions, I'm facing a problem when I'm trying to implement live ListView filtering, when user enters some text in search bar, which is located in the Action Bar. 
P.S. I didn't even hav Log.i("Nomad", "onQueryTextChange") in onQueryTextChange() printed in the log, when I'm debugging the application :/

AllLists.java

```
public class AllLists extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
private Context context;
private int position = 0;
private String location;
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
private SearchView mSearchView;

public AllLists(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alllists, container, false);
    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
  //  View list_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.small_icon);
    header.setClickable(false);
   // ImageView logo = (ImageView) list_view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    position = bundle.getInt("position");
    location = bundle.getString("location");
    image.setImageDrawable(navMenuIcons.getDrawable(position));
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    items = db.getAllItems(location);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(context, items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.addHeaderView(header);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (location.equals("accommodation") || location.equals("eat") || location.equals("events")
                    || location.equals("entertainment") || location.equals("places") || location.equals("cinema")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, ItemScreen.class);
                i.putExtra("position", position - 1);
                i.putExtra("location", location);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return rootView;
}

/*SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener){

}*/

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
    Log.i("Nomad", "onQueryTextChange");
    adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
    return false;
}
}
```

CustomListAdapter.java

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<Item> items;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
private List<Item> filteredData;


public CustomListAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView image = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
    Item i = items.get(position);
    // Log.d("FOTO linkas: " + i.getName() + " ", i.getIcon());
    if (i.getIcon().contains("http")) {
        //   Log.d("suveike: ", i.getIcon());
        image.setImageUrl(i.getIcon(), imageLoader);
    }/*else if(items.get(0).getName().contains("taksi")) {
        Log.d("suveike: ", "else if");
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
    }*/ else
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
    name.setText(i.getName());
    type.setText(i.getType());
    return convertView;
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0) {
                results.values = items;
                results.count = items.size();
            } else {
                List<Item> filtered_items = new ArrayList<Item>();

                for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                    if (items.get(i).getName().contains(charSequence))
                        filtered_items.add(items.get(i));
                }

                results.values = filtered_items;
                results.count = filtered_items.size();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            filteredData = (List<Item>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
}
```

Comment: When I write some text to the searchview to filter, it doesn't filter the listview.

Comment: why did you implement two OnQueryTextListeners?

Comment: Could you, please, post the corrected code? I'm out of ideas, what else could I do...

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong yet, but I have noticed that you use 2 OnQueryTextListener. One from here implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, and the 2nd here mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(). Remove one of them and put some logs into the one you keep and see if the listener gets triggerd when you type some text.

Comment: I have tried removing both OnQueryTextListeners seperately, but it didn't help...

Answer (score 0):

You have to type listView.setAdapter(adapter) after adapter.getFilter().filter(s) in onQueryTextChange. That will refresh the listView.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the fact, that I don't have     Log.i("Nomad", "onQueryTextChange"); printed in my log...

Comment: I couldn't understand your comment. All I am saying is inside your onQueryTextChange method, you are doing adapter.getFilter().filter(s). After this, you need to call listView.setAdapter(adapter). This will refresh the data in the listview.

Comment: All I'm trying to explain, is, that the OnQueryTextListener isn't excecuted, because Log.i("Nomad", "onQueryTextChange"); isn't printed at all, when I'm debugging the app and enter the query...

Comment: Well then, you can try this..Dont do implements SearchView.onQueryTextChangeListner..Instead in onCreateView, write    the following code

Answer (score 0):

Well then, you can try this..Don't do implements SearchView.onQueryTextChangeListner..
Instead in onCreateView, write    the following

```
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() 
        {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                //your code here                
            return false;
        }

    });
```